# Node.js Axios post request to API with cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I want to provide cookie in POST request with Axios. I have a zeppelin API which works with CURL as:

```
curl -i --data 'userName=admin&password=admin' -X POST http://zeppelin.XXXXX.net/api/login
```

and response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD, DELETE
Content-Length: 127
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wednesday, September 1, 2021 8:20:55 AM UTC
Server: Jetty(9.4.14.v20181114)
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 31-Aug-2021 08:20:55 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=a3a4392d-1347-47b6-b85b-61230e16802b; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 31-Aug-2021 08:20:55 GMT
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 31-Aug-2021 08:20:55 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=14acf05d-3cb3-4548-b8e3-6066caf90000; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 31-Aug-2021 08:20:55 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1
```

To use a note in zeppelin

```
curl -i -b 'JSESSIONID=14acf05d-3cb3-4548-b8e3-6066caf90000; Path=/; HttpOnly' -X POST http://zeppelin.XXXXXX.net/api/notebook/job/2G9P1992Z/20210615-091750_1582099873
```

succeeds with

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD, DELETE
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wednesday, September 1, 2021 8:28:07 AM UTC
Server: Jetty(9.4.14.v20181114)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1
```

I have a function to login and get the cookie

```
const axios = require('axios')
const setCookie = require('set-cookie-parser');

const zeppelinLoginCoockie = async function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
        .post(process.env.ZEPPELIN_URL + 'login', 'userName=admin&password=admin')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`);
            //console.log(res);
            let cookies = setCookie.parse(res, {
                decodeValues: true  // default: true
              });
            let lastSessionId = 'null';
            cookies.forEach(element => {
                if ( element.name === 'JSESSIONID' ) {
                    lastSessionId = element.value;
                };
            });
            //console.log(cookies);
            return resolve(lastSessionId);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            return reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

which works, but now I don't know how to do the second command to launch the note.

I tried to provide cookie as in:

```
const zeppelinNoteRun = async function(loginCookie){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const cookieHeader = `JSESSIONID=${loginCookie}; Path=/; HttpOnly`
        axios
        .post(process.env.ZEPPELIN_URL + 'notebook/job/2G9P1992Z/20210615-091750_1582099873', {
            headers:{
                cookie: cookieHeader
            } 
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`);
            return resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            return reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

I am not proficient with Axios or cookies, so I'm interested to know how to perform such a task?

EDIT: a typo in url in node, though the accepted answer was the final solution.

Comment: I've read it works only with browsers. But tried this now and I get ```Error: Request failed with status code 405```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed the object containing cookie as the POST data.
Try to add a null after the 1st argument of axios.post

```js
axios.post(url, null, {
  headers:{
    cookie: cookieHeader
  } 
})
```

#### axios.post() signature

```
axios#post(url[, data[, config]])
```

[axios post method](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1)

BTW, overwriting the `Cookie` header in browser side won't work by design, no matter you use native fetch or browser side axios, see [Forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name).

Comment: Tried this and now the cookie is there correctly but I get 404 and ```Cookie: 'JSESSIONID=c0017ad6-d120-46bc-8fd6-a54d0f0275c7; Path=/; HttpOnly', 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1' ``` With curl I get ```Cookie: JSESSIONID=14acf05d-3cb3-4548-b8e3-6066caf90000; Path=/; HttpOnly``` with --verbose ( different instance so diff cookie)

Comment: @eemilk Don't add path info in the cookie when you're making request, use `cookie: 'a=1; b=2'` plz.

Comment: Still 404. I tiried with just ```JSESSIONID=${loginCookie}``` and ```loginCookie``` and ```JSESSIONID=${loginCookie}; HttpOnly```

Comment: @eemilk full log??

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ia96KZ1E <- full log in the pastebin site

Comment: Hey it worked... I had a really embarrassing mistake in the url... But with your further advise it worked. So ```Cookie: 'JSESSIONID=${loginCookie}'``` and having the data set to ```null```